# open text file with key/value into combobox winforms

Tags: c#

I am having some difficulty to use a text file that contains key=value entries (ex: ABCD=ABCD) and use a dictionary defined in my C# program to open that file to be used as a combobox.

Below is my current code which I have statically defined the key/value field using add (the whole list has about 30 entries).

```
Dictionary<string, string> vendors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
vendors.Add("ADVENE", "ADVENE");
vendors.Add("DFG RISK", "DFG RISK");

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn vendcol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
vendcol.Name = "vendor";
vendcol.HeaderText = "Vendor";
vendcol.DisplayMember = "Value";
vendcol.ValueMember = "Key";
vendcol.DataSource = vendors.ToList();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(vendcol);
```

How do I convert the above key/value entries into a text file and have it used by a combobox when opening application?

I have tried to use `StreamReader` but I am completely lost on how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: It is not very clear what are you asking. Do you want to know how to read a text file where each line is composed by a string in the format KEY=VALUE?

Comment: And why do you need a dictionary? Do you have lines with the same KEY but different values?

Comment: Do you plan on the user to be able to add to the combobox new data and to save it back to the text file for later uses ?

Comment: @Franck: the reason to use a text file is to allow user to modify vendor list because I couldn't figure out a way to dynamically grow the current combobox to add something that is not there via drop down. So I figured that only way that would be easier for user is to add to text file whenever they want to add another vendor.  Unless you know how to add to combobox at runtime and keep added vendor for next time user runs program??

Comment: @Steve: the reason I used the dictionary is that the previous person who created this program did so, trying to keep his code without modifying the whole thing.  The key and value are different.

Comment: @RashmiPatel You can add item to combobox if you do set `comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`. then user can type text in it and i don't remember if you need to check for `Enter` being pressed in `KeyPress` event or if it's `Validated` event but you can add the value as an item of the `ComboBox`. You can resave all the `ComboBox` item to the text file afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your text file has the following format:

```
ADVENE=ADVENE
DFG RISK=DFG RISK
```

You can parse it using the following code:

```
var vendors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt"))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] keyValue = line.Split(new char[] { '=' });
        vendors.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }
}
```

To populate the `DataGridViewColumn` you can try the following:

```
var vendcol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
vendcol.HeaderText = "Vendor";
vendcol.ValueMember = "Key";
vendcol.DisplayMember = "Value";
vendcol.DataSource = vendors.ToArray();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(vendcol);
```

Comment: do I need to change any of this code:                                    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn vendcol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
vendcol.Name = "vendor";
vendcol.HeaderText = "Vendor";
vendcol.DisplayMember = "Value";
vendcol.ValueMember = "Key";
vendcol.DataSource = vendors.ToList();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(vendcol);

Comment: Thanks still seems to not working after implementing your suggestion.  Still pulls old data into the combobox

Comment: I figured it out, found I had to change it in 2 different forms.

Comment: I am trying to sort the input file prior to viewing in drop down list, how do I achieve this?  I have tried using linq method but can't seem to figure it out using above code.

Comment: Use a SortedDictionary<string, string>() instead of a Dictionary<string, string>()

Comment: Thanks that did it!